# angular.js element has no method querySelector

Tags: angularjs, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get a child element from angular as an object in my directive, so I have

```
link: function(scope,elem,attrs){
    var resizeBar = elem.querySelector('.resize-bar');
```

When I output the `elem`, I have an html object. 
However, I get an error `Object [object object] has no method 'querySelector'.

I can get the element using

```
   var resizeBar = elem.children().children()[1];
```

but that outputs as

```
<div class="resize-bar">Move</div>
```

which isn't what I need, I need the html object of the resize-bar.

Anybody know of a good way to do this in angular?

console output of elem  is

```
: div.favor-layout.favor-layout-sideways
accessKey: ""
align: ""
attributes: NamedNodeMap
baseURI: "file:///C:/Users/pete/projects/favor/favor-layout/index.html"
childElementCount: 1
childNodes: NodeList[2]
children: HTMLCollection[1]
classList: DOMTokenList
className: "favor-layout favor-layout-sideways"
clientHeight: 200
clientLeft: 0
clientTop: 0
clientWidth: 913
contentEditable: "inherit"
dataset: DOMStringMap
dir: ""
draggable: false
firstChild: div.favor-layout-container
firstElementChild: div.favor-layout-container
hidden: false
id: ""
innerHTML: "↵   ↵          This gets wrapped.↵     ↵ move↵↵"
innerText: "This gets wrapped.↵move"
isContentEditable: false
lang: ""
lastChild: text
lastElementChild: div.favor-layout-container
localName: "div"
namespaceURI: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
nextElementSibling: null
nextSibling: text
nodeName: "DIV"
nodeType: 1
nodeValue: null
offsetHeight: 200
offsetLeft: 8
offsetParent: body.ng-scope
offsetTop: 8
offsetWidth: 913
onabort: null
onbeforecopy: null
onbeforecut: null
onbeforepaste: null
onblur: null
oncancel: null
oncanplay: null
oncanplaythrough: null
onchange: null
onclick: null
onclose: null
oncontextmenu: null
oncopy: null
oncuechange: null
oncut: null
ondblclick: null
ondrag: null
ondragend: null
ondragenter: null
ondragleave: null
ondragover: null
ondragstart: null
ondrop: null
ondurationchange: null
onemptied: null
onended: null
onerror: null
onfocus: null
oninput: null
oninvalid: null
onkeydown: null
onkeypress: null
onkeyup: null
onload: null
onloadeddata: null
onloadedmetadata: null
onloadstart: null
onmousedown: null
onmouseenter: null
onmouseleave: null
onmousemove: null
onmouseout: null
onmouseover: null
onmouseup: null
onmousewheel: null
onpaste: null
onpause: null
onplay: null
onplaying: null
onprogress: null
onratechange: null
onreset: null
onscroll: null
onsearch: null
onseeked: null
onseeking: null
onselect: null
onselectstart: null
onshow: null
onstalled: null
onsubmit: null
onsuspend: null
ontimeupdate: null
onvolumechange: null
onwaiting: null
onwebkitfullscreenchange: null
onwebkitfullscreenerror: null
onwheel: null
outerHTML: "↵   ↵          This gets wrapped.↵     ↵ move↵↵"
outerText: "This gets wrapped.↵move"
ownerDocument: document
parentElement: body.ng-scope
parentNode: body.ng-scope
prefix: null
previousElementSibling: null
previousSibling: text
scrollHeight: 200
scrollLeft: 0
scrollTop: 0
scrollWidth: 913
spellcheck: true
style: CSSStyleDeclaration
tabIndex: -1
tagName: "DIV"
textContent: "↵ ↵           This gets wrapped.↵     ↵   move↵↵"
title: ""
translate: true
webkitPseudo: ""
webkitShadowRoot: null
webkitdropzone: ""
__proto__: HTMLDivElement
context: div.favor-layout.favor-layout-sideways
length: 1
__proto__: Object[0]
```

Answer (score 25):

try this, the return value is element, not angular element.

```
var resizeBar = elem[0].querySelector('.resize-bar');
```

Comment: write a example [http://plnkr.co/edit/A4w6Gd?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/A4w6Gd?p=preview)

Comment: I support this answer.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to find an element that resides ***within*** your directive's template, you can use this within your `link` function:

```
var divElement = angular.element(element[0].querySelector('#find-me'));
```

It will look for the `#find-me` id. But it will do so only *within your directive's **template***. So, it won't return any elements with the same id outside of your directive, like `document.querySelector("#find-me")` would.

So, if you were to use it in a directive, it would look like this:

```
angular.module('app').directive('myDirective', function(){
    return{
        link: function(scope, element, attributes){
            var divElement = angular.element(element[0].querySelector('#find-me'));
        },
        template: function(element, attributes){
            return '<div id="find-me">' +
                        'Look at my directive' +
                    '</div>';
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`.querySelector()` is a method of `document`. However, since you've got `elem` going, you can do this:

```
var currentElemClass = "." + elem.className.replace(/\s/g, ".") + " ";
var resizeBar = document.querySelector(currentElemClass + ".resize-bar");
```

What this does is it gets the classname of the current element, then adds it to the beginning of `document.querySelector` so that you've got an accurate query.

So as an example, with this being applied to `div.favor-layout.favor-layout-sideways`, `currentElemClass` becomes `.favor-layout.favor-layout-sideways`, so in the end your you get:

```
document.querySelector(".favor-layout.favor-layout-sideways .resize-bar");
```

Which is a valid query.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to do this without jQuery, but might give up on that.  The problem with your solution is when I put resizeBar to the console, it gives me the html string, not the object.

Comment: Could you paste the response of `console.log(elem)` in your directive?

Comment: added the console.log of elem

Comment: that's a great idea knrz, I'll take a closer look at it, but the problem I'm having is that I'll have many divs with the same group of classes and this would get them all. I'll take a look at adding an id, but I may not have a unique data related to each div to create an id from.

Comment: querySelector is an element method so it works not just on document https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector